# Ranking functions in TFIDF sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, information-retrieval, tf-idf

I have used sklearn TFIDFVectorizer to build a weight matrix from a given set of documents. I want to perform queries using a ranking function based on the terms of the query, it can be the a simple function like the sum of the terms weights in the query.

Is there any way of doing such kind of queries in sklearn (preferably in a efficient way)?, or maybe a python framework to handle that kind of work.

So far what I've got is the following:

```
items.sort(key= lambda x : -sum(tfidf_matrix[x, term_id]) for term_id in query_terms))
```

So I'm sorting the items according to the terms in the query. But I'd like to know if there is a built-in way to do this and of course, more efficiently. Because do a sorting with each query is not an option with a big amount of requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question may have been too broad, I ended up using a framework like lucene that handles document search anb indexing in a very efficient way instead of going by a naive approach computing tf-idf matrices.